# Is a batsman out if the bails are removed but fall back onto the stumps?

Tags: rules, cricket

Let me know what happens to the batsman in this situation.

> The spin bowler made an magic delivery so that it hit the stumps and a bail is pushed out of its position (the grooves), but didn't fall to the ground, rather it balanced on top of one of the stumps.

I know it's an extremely weird and rare scenario, but I'm too curious to know the decision of the umpire.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not out. Quoting from Law 30.1(a):

> The striker is out Bowled if his wicket is put down by a ball delivered by the bowler

and Law 28.1:

> (a) The wicket is put down if a bail is completely removed from the top of the stumps
>
> [...]
>
> (b) The disturbance of a bail, whether temporary or not, shall not constitute its complete removal from the top of the stumps